# How to compare data with varying number of values

Tags: php, mysql, data-comparison

I'll try to explain my problem as well as I can.

I have to compare data of same type, saved in a MySql database but containing a varying number of values.

I build my database like this (probably not the best):

```
--
-- Table structure for table `amount`
--

CREATE TABLE `amount` (
  `id` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `value` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `amount`
--

INSERT INTO `amount` (`id`, `value`) VALUES
(34, 1),
(22, 2),
(30, 6),
(21, 7),
(9, 8),
(17, 9),
(10, 10),
(15, 11),
(3, 12),
(4, 13),
(8, 14),
(5, 15),
(16, 16),
(13, 17),
(6, 18),
(20, 19),
(7, 20),
(23, 21),
(18, 22),
(19, 23),
(24, 24),
(14, 25),
(25, 26),
(26, 27),
(28, 28),
(29, 29),
(11, 30),
(27, 31),
(12, 32),
(31, 33),
(32, 35),
(33, 36),
(2, 98),
(1, 99);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `mark`
--

CREATE TABLE `mark` (
  `id` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `mark`
--

INSERT INTO `mark` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C'),
(4, 'D'),
(5, 'E'),
(6, 'F'),
(7, 'G'),
(8, 'H'),
(9, 'I'),
(10, 'J')
(11, 'K')
(12, 'L')
(13, 'M')
(14, 'N')
(15, 'O');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `profile`
--

CREATE TABLE `profile` (
  `id` smallint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `run` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `validated` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `profile_mark`
--

CREATE TABLE `profile_mark` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_profile` smallint(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_mark` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_amount` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Each time new data arrive, a profile is created and if necessary a new mark and a new amount.

- A profile have a fixed number of mark (9, 16, 24)
- For each profile, each of its mark can have 0, 1 or 2 amount

It means a profile can have up to 48 values. I plan to have at least 20000 profile in database in the future.

**My Goal:** If I take one profile, I must find all other profiles which have at least 1 common value for X of their marks. (where X is the number of marks minimum which must match)

At the moment, I take all profiles one by one to compare it to the tested one. It takes a some time (I have only about 50 profile at the moment in database) and it's not a good solution for the future of my application.

Another solution I imagine is to cache (or save in database), all profile id for each mark_amount association... but It seems not a good idea :(

I need some advise to optimize this comparison please.
(I'm open to other database, cache system than php/mysql  etc...)

**EDIT1:** example of profile matching or not on 8 marks

> https://jsfiddle.net/gafy2w4k/

Comment: Is there a reason to store amounts and marks in separate tables and then reference them through ID and not just use the actual value?

Comment: I though it was judicious in fact, because profiles don't have all the same number of mark, can have different mark and new mark can be added. I though it was easier to compare IDs than marks' names which length can vary. (marks in the code above are not those I have in my db). Concerning the values... I'm not sure of the way I choose to reference it.

Comment: Could you add an example data of the a target profile, a profile that "has at least 1 common value for X of their marks.", and a profile that doesn't. The matching criteria is a bit vague, so examples should make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query to return all `profile_mark.id_profile` that have **exactly** `@matched_marks` marks with at least 1 same amount as the profile with the given `@target_profile_id`:

```
SELECT `match`.id_profile, count(*) as X FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `all`.id_profile, `all`.id_mark FROM profile_mark as `all`
    INNER JOIN profile_mark as `one` 
      ON `one`.id_mark = `all`.id_mark 
      AND `one`.id_amount = `all`.id_amount
    WHERE `all`.id_profile <> @target_profile_id
      AND `one`.id_profile = @target_profile_id
) as `match`
GROUP BY 1
HAVING X = @matched_marks; // can be >= if you need at least X matching marks
```

As a side note, `id_profile smallint(2)` seems insufficient for *at least 20000 profiles*.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88edbf/7 has data from your table in SQL format.

Comment: Awesome, it works very well. 
I'll maybe have to adapt it to some configuration option but it does what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it doesn't give me what I exactly need in fact but I'm very close to the wanted result ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The is question needs more details but I see a couple of general improvements that'll be useful here :
First, I don't see any indexes, please make PRIMARY KEY for every id
Example :

```
CREATE TABLE `mark` (
  `id` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  ...
```

If it's too late to change the tables , use `CREATE INDEX`

Second, for consistency sake make REFERENCES to declare foreign key dependency
example:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id_mark) REFERENCES mark(id)
```

Finally, run `EXPLAIN` statement on your query, and see what you can improve according to the result (you can add index for queries that are frequently used to )
`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: concerning pk, fk and indexes, they don't appear in my code but I have it in my db, just forget to copy it :(